Error during cab file installation in windows server 2019
When we run dism command in cmd for installation manual patch of KB5003282 of cab file in windows 2019 server. We are getting error is the specified package is not applicable to this image.

The error message completely explains what is wrong... once you understand that KBs actually come in different flavors for different platforms. If you try to install KB5003282 for Windows 10 on Server 2019 you'll get this error. Go back to where you got the KB from and retrieve the specific version of this patch for your OS.

Two things:

KB5003282 is the May 2021 Service Stack Update (SSU) for Windows Server 2019 Azure Stack HCI Edition 20H2/21H2. KB5003282 was superseded in June 2021 by SSU KB5004179. KB5003282 is not relevant to your system due to the system has more recent updates installed, even if another tool specifies that it is needed.

Windows Server 2019 Azure Stack HCI Edition 20H2/21H2 is end of life effective November 2023.



https://docs.azure.cn/en-us/azure-stack/hci/concepts/updates
